# f2, f3, f4 identifier not found

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1() {
    cout << "I am function one" << endl;
    f2();
}
void f2() {
    cout << "I am function two" << endl;
    f3();
}
void f3() {
    cout << "I am function three" << endl;
    f4();
}
void f4() {
    cout << "I am function four" << endl;
}
int main(){
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors**:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   C3861   'funkcija2': identifier not found   ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\bakir\Desktop\C++\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp  7       
Error   C3861   'funkcija3': identifier not found   ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\bakir\Desktop\C++\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp  11      
Error   C3861   'funkcija4': identifier not found   ConsoleApplication5 C:\Users\bakir\Desktop\C++\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp  15
```

Comment: In C++ you must declare all symbols *before* you use them. In `f1` the compiler doesn't know anything about the symbol `f2`, because `f2` haven't been declared yet.

Comment: For future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please make sure that the [mcve] you show match the error messages you show.

Comment: Congrats, you just discovered why C++ projects almost always have separate "header" and "source" files :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C++` requires symbols to be declared before use.
You can declare your functions next way

```
void f1();
void f2();
void f3();
void f4();
```

before you use them in implementation.

The alternative would be reshuffle your implementation

```
void f4() {
    cout << "I am function four" << endl;
}
void f3() {
    cout << "I am function three" << endl;
    f4();
}
void f2() {
    cout << "I am function two" << endl;
    f3();
}
void f1() {
    cout << "I am function one" << endl;
    f2();
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help :)